# How to allocate memory for for a structure inside of a stucture? (in C)

Tags: c

So I have these structures

```
// structures.
typedef struct{
    char *name;
    int price;
    double weight;
}item;

typedef struct{
    item **items;
    int num_items;
}inventory;

typedef struct{
    char *name;
    int level;
    long xp;
    inventory Inventory;
}character;
```

I was already able to create a character with a function and then call another function to view that character, But I can't figure how to allocate space for and item or inventory.

```
inventory *add_item(inventory *invp){
        if(invp == NULL){
            inventory *invp = calloc(1, sizeof(inventory)); // Allocating memory for inventory
            items = calloc(1, sizeof(items *)); // need to allocate space for the item **items
            char buffer[buf] = { 0 };
            printf("Enter name: ");                
            fgets(buffer, buf, stdin);
            remove_newline(buffer);
            items->new_item->name = (strlen(buffer) + 1, sizeof(char));
            strcpy(items->new_item->name, buffer);
    
            printf("Enter price: ");
            scanf("%d", &items->new_item->price);
            while(getchar() != '\n');
    
            printf("Enter weight: ");
            scanf("%ld", &items->new_item->weight);
            while(getchar() != '\n');
    
            return items; // <---- this is the new character just created.    }
    
        }
}
```

---

this is my create a character function

```
character *create_character(character *c){  // input to this function->address to a structure.
      
    if(c == NULL){
        char buffer[buf] = { 0 };                                  // (so a pointer.)
        character *c = calloc(1, sizeof(character));

        printf("Enter charcter name: ");
        fgets(buffer, buf, stdin);
        remove_newline(buffer); // removing the new line.

        c->name = calloc(strlen(buffer) + 1, sizeof(char)); //allocating memory for character
        strcpy(c->name, buffer);  // copying input into memory just allocated.

        printf("Enter level: ");
        scanf("%d", &c->level);
        while(getchar() != '\n');

        printf("Enter XP: ");
        scanf("%ld", &c->xp);
        while(getchar() != '\n');

        c->Inventory = calloc(1, sizeof(inventory));

        return c; // <---- this is the new character just created.    }

    }else {
        printf("ERROR: Character Already Exist.\n");
    }
        
}
```

I was trying to use the same format that I used to create a character to create the item, but the pointer part is confusing me, do I initialize an inventory inside c, and then calloc the **items to be ba able to create an item?

Comment: Since `Inventory` is an instance of the `inventory` structure, its memory is allocated together with the surrounding `character` structure.

Comment: As for the `inventory` structure, why do you think you need pointer to pointer for `items`? What is your thoughts and analysis and design that made you think that would be a good decision? Also, considering that a characters inventory could be dynamic, why not make it a linked list where you can add and remove nodes easily?

Comment: well because this is an assignment for a class, and the structures were given. The reason I didn't use a link list is because it is only one character that can be made so I didn't think it was necessary. So are you saying to make a link list that could hold the structures together?

Comment: there was another question regarding the same task couple of days ago. basically the same problem or question arises. how do you add an item with the given inventory structure without knowing its maximum capacity? i cant think of a possibility, except of deep copying the whole inventory struct with all its items and then creating a new one with newly allocated memory for one extra item. this seems like an unreasonable solution..